# PHP Mailer --- Reply-to: --- Return-path --- SetFrom

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I am sending mail via PHP Mailer. http://phpmailer.worxware.com/

I want to be able to set the From to one emailand the REPLY-TO to another email and the RETURN-PATH to yet another.

Mainly.. I want the bounced emails to go to something like BOUNCEDemails@bademail.com
I was hoping the RETURN PATH could do this.

And if a user who gets the email I don't want them to see its from BOUNCEDemails etc.. to I want to give them an option to reply to a real email address.

I need the bounced emails tho to go to a seperate email because I don't want the REPLY TO to get many bad emails. etc..

**HERE IS WHAT I HAVE: Does Not work**

```
$mail->AddAddress('ed@RealEmail.org', 'John Doe');
$mail->AddReplyTo('replytoMe@email.com', 'Reply to email');
$mail->SetFrom('mailbox@email.com', 'From Name and Email');
$mail->AddCustomHeader('Return-path: BOUNCEDemails@bademail.com');
```

The code above replies to SetFrom and sends all bounces to SetFrom. Any ideas how to separate the two? Thanks

Comment: Check that you're using the most recent version of PHPMailer:  https://github.com/Synchro/PHPMailer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the correct way to set this (as of july 2013) is by using:

```
$mail->ReturnPath='bounce_here@domain.com';
```

the phpmailer source contains the following, which is fairly self explanatory:

```
if ($this->ReturnPath) {
  $result .= $this->HeaderLine('Return-Path', '<'.trim($this->ReturnPath).'>');
} elseif ($this->Sender == '') {
  $result .= $this->HeaderLine('Return-Path', '<'.trim($this->From).'>');
} else {
  $result .= $this->HeaderLine('Return-Path', '<'.trim($this->Sender).'>');
}
```

Comment: As of Nov 2014 this appears deprecated http://phpmailer.github.io/PHPMailer/classes/PHPMailer.html#property_ReturnPath

Comment: I think this is wrong. The `Return-Path` gets set by the receiving MTA based on the `Sender` header, and any `Return-Path` header you set gets ignored. That's why PHPMailer deprecated the functionality and their inline docs say you should never set `Return-Path`.

Answer (score 2):

You may use

```
$mail->AddReplyTo('name@yourdomain.com', 'First Last');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$mail->AddReplyTo('replytoMe@email.com', 'Reply to email');
$mail->AddAddress('ed@RealEmail.org', 'John Doe');
```

Notice the order! AddReplyTo has to be BEFORE AddAddress!!!